# client:43 [GSI_LOGGER]: The value of 'callback' is not a function. Configuration ignored. (Angular)

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Friends, I have followed the instruction provided by [Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/client-library) to integration Google Login in Angular app. I have spent almost three days and tried out most possible solutions suggested over here. So, please help me out to fix this issue.

**Problem Statement:** On start of the application **handleCredentialResponse** callback method is recognized but on reloading the same page, I am getting the error - **callback is not a function**

> I do understand this - handleCredentialResponse needs to be global
> (window) scope.

But I am not able to figure out how to achieve this. I am also curious to know how browser is able to identify the callback on start of the application but not able to find it later.

index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Created a script file to define callback function
**google-login-provider.ts**

```js
window.handleCredentialResponse = function (response) {
    // decodeJwtResponse() is a custom function defined by you
    // to decode the credential response.
    const responsePayload = decodeJwtResponse(response.credential);
    console.log("Handle Credential Response called.");
    console.log("ID: " + responsePayload.sub);
    console.log("Full Name: " + responsePayload.name);
    console.log("Given Name: " + responsePayload.given_name);
    console.log("Family Name: " + responsePayload.family_name);
    console.log("Image URL: " + responsePayload.picture);
    console.log("Email: " + responsePayload.email);
};
function decodeJwtResponse(token) {
    var base64Url = token.split(".")[1];
    var base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, "+").replace(/_/g, "/");
    var jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(
        window
            .atob(base64)
            .split("")
            .map(function (c) {
                return "%" + ("00" + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
            })
            .join("")
    );

    return JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
}
```

Definig the Google HTML DiV in app.component.html

```html
<div>
   <div
      id="g_id_onload"
      data-client_id="using correct client id here"
      data-context="signin"
      data-ux_mode="popup"
      data-callback="handleCredentialResponse"
      data-nonce=""
      data-auto_prompt="true"
    ></div>
    <div
      class="g_id_signin"
      data-type="standard"
      data-shape="rectangular"
      data-theme="outline"
      data-text="signin_with"
      data-size="large"
      data-logo_alignment="left"
    ></div>
</div>
```

Loaded the above script file in app.component.ts file

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.loadGoogleLoginProviderJs();
}

loadGoogleLoginProviderJs() {
  console.log("Loading google script");
  const js = 'assets/google-login-provider.js';
  const node = document.createElement('script');
  node.src = js;
  node.type = 'text/javascript';
  node.async = true;
  node.defer = true;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
}
```

On starting the application, there is no callback issue, I am able to fetch user details from Google.
[image]

On reloading the same page, getting the callback function error.
[image]